# How to access class without object?

Tags: java

How can we access class without its object in Java programming language?

How can we access the class without not using object?

```
class test{
//elements of class
}
```

Comment: do you know what 'static' is/does?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what do you want to do.

If you want to a call method of the class, then according to OOP the simple answer is "you cannot". One must create an object to invoke methods.

Java has a special methods type - **static methods**. This sort of methods can be invoked using the class name instead of the object name:

```
public class Test {
     public void someMethod() {
          // do something  
     }
     public static void someStaticMethod() {
          // do something
     }
}
```

Like this:

```
// calling non-static method
Test instanceOfTest = new Test();
instanceOfTest.someMethod();

// calling static method
Test.someStaticMethod();
```

Static methods are not covered by the classical OOP theory. It is a workaround provided by Java to support elements of functional programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can access class even without making any `object`.
We normally make instances to use the `methods` and the `attributes` of the class.
However you can define some `methods` and `attributes` which are called `static`s, these methods or attributes are for the class and not for the objects, so you can access those, just with the class:
Assume this example:

```java
class Test{
    public static void testStaticMethod(){
        System.out.println("This method is static");
    }
}
```

You can access the `testStaticMethod` just by the class and without `instantiating` any `objects`:

```java
class TestTester{
   public static void main(String[] args){
       Test.testStaticMethod()
   }
}
```

Output:

```
This method is static
```